# Removing sidebar from a single beamer frame

Tags: beamer, themes

I like using the Beamer Goettingen theme as it has a nice sidebar. I would like to remove this from occasional slides, so the text can go all the way across. However, while the [plain] option removes the side bar, the text still wraps as if the side bar were there (minimal worked example below). How do I get text to wrap across slide?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]{title}

\lipsum

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `geometry` package for that. The idea is to use a `\newgeometry` before `\begin{frame}` and use `\restoregeometry` right after `\end{frame}`. Take a look at `geometry` docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}

\lipsum

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]{title}
\advance\textwidth2cm
\hsize\textwidth
\columnwidth\textwidth
\lipsum

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain the three specific lines, advance, hsize and column width? Thanks!!

Comment: @Matifou it is better to ask a question rather than comment on 5 year old answers but iin latex those lines should have been `\addtolength\textwidth{2cm} \setlength\hsize{\textwidth} \setlength\columnwidth{\textwidth}`  it just makes all three of those lengths be 2cm more than they were

Answer (score 4):

Based on David's answer, you can do the following. I also suggest you to remove the navigation symbols because with this approach there is a problem in the `specialframe`.

```
\documentclass[c]{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % removes navigation symbols

\newenvironment{specialframe}
{
    \begingroup
    \advance\textwidth2cm % see beamerthemeGoettingen.sty for the number
    \hsize\textwidth
    \columnwidth\textwidth
    \begin{frame}[plain]
}
{
    \end{frame}
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{specialframe}
\frametitle{This is a special frame}

\lipsum[1]

\end{specialframe}

\begin{frame}{No special frame}

\lipsum[2]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How would you adapt that code if instead the sidebar was on the left (as in theme Berkeley)? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe replacing `\advance\textwidth2cm` with `\advance\leftskip-0.3cm` or something. But I didn't had the time to check.