# Pages w/o side bar (package beamer)

Tags: beamer

Hope this is not an FAQ.

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=294912

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=294913

The submitter uses a theme, which is designed to have side bars (`Berkeley`). Now he wants to have a page w/o side bar and writes:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \begin{center}
   lot of text to see the effect: lorem ipsum....
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
```

He expects that the text is centered now, but this is not the case; the side bar is still regarded when placing the text. Same for images:

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
   \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
     \includegraphics{image}
   }
\end{frame}
```

Minimal example for testing can be provided.

Before opening a useless ticket @the beamer maintainers: FAD or bug? Of course it works fine when using a theme not having side bars (e.g. `Madrid`).

Many thanks!
  Hilmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, but much closer than the default. Working from [Removing sidebar from a single beamer frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113410/removing-sidebar-from-a-single-beamer-frame):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berkeley}

\newenvironment{specialframe}
{
    \begingroup
    \advance\hoffset-2.5\baselineskip % beamerouterthemesidebar.sty, line 16
    \advance\hoffset-0.3cm  % beamerouterthemesidebar.sty, line 47
    \advance\textwidth2.5\baselineskip
    \advance\textwidth0.3cm
    \hsize\textwidth
    \columnwidth\textwidth
    \begin{frame}[plain]
}
{
    \end{frame}
    \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{specialframe}
   \begin{center}
     This should be \textbf{really} centered horizontally!

     Unfortunately it is only centered according to the display
     area while the frame on the left side remains even if \texttt{\[plain\]}
     was given as option to the frame environment.

     The next frame is a try to cover the \textbf{whole} screen with an
     image.
  \end{center}
\end{specialframe}

\begin{specialframe}
   \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
     \includegraphics{example-image-a}
  }
\end{specialframe}

\begin{frame}
Here's a regular frame.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks! However I wasn't looking for a solution of the problem, but rather for an opinion if the observed behavior is a bug or not. If yes, I'd open a ticket @ the beamer tracking system.

Comment: Only the maintainers can say if it's working as intended. But I'd agree it's odd to have a plain page with invisible asymmetric margins.